# How to access Swagger UI or How to exclude Swagger UI from resource server if it is integrated with authorization server

Tags: microservices, swagger-ui, spring-boot-security, oauth2resourceserver, spring-boot-oauth2.1

I have implemented **Authorization Server** microservice (auth-service) with oauth2 and OpenId standards for authentication and authorization using new spring boot security version 3.2. Also
I have implemented another microservice (api-service) for **Resource Server** with Swagger v3. All protected resources is present in this microservice. To access these protected resources from Resource Server (api-service) i am using access-token (JWT) which is generated from the auth-service. **The problem is**  I have excluded the swagger related endpoints from security still i am getting **Unauthorized** response and swagger ui is not loading at all.
If anyone know how to solve this please let me know. I have tried multiple things but its not working.

Following is my Yaml and resource server configuration

**YAML CONFIGURATION:**

logging:
level:
root: INFO
org.springframework.web: DEBUG
org.springframework.security: DEBUG
org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG

spring:
security:
oauth2:
resourceserver:
jwt:
issuer-uri: http://localhost:8089
jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8089/oauth2/jwks

**RESOURCE SERVER CONFIGURATION:**

```
@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
private String contextPath;

/**
 * Publicly accessible urls i.e., not secured url, auth service will ignore this URLs
 *
 * @return String[] of urls
 */
private String[] publicAPI() {
    return Stream.of(
            "/css/**",
            "/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/v3/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/*/swagger-resources/**",
            "/*/v3/api-docs"
    ).toArray(String[]::new);
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .ignoringRequestMatchers(publicAPI())
    ).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(publicAPI()).permitAll()

            ).oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer ->
                    resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
            );

    return http.build();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Its so silly mistake i forgot to add @Configuration annotation to my class.. its working now